# Maximum of $\frac{x^{15}(1-x)y^{15}(1-y)}{(1-xy)^{15}}$ where $x,y\in(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, maxima-minima

> I need maximum of $$ \frac{x^{15}(1-x)y^{15}(1-y)}{(1-xy)^{15}}$$ where $0<x<1$, $0<y<1$

Define $$ f(x,y)=\frac{x^{15}(1-x)y^{15}(1-y)}{(1-xy)^{15}}$$
So the function is positive for $0<x<1$, $0<y<1$ and vanishes on the boundary $x=0$ or $x=1$ or $y=0$ or $y=1$. Therefore it attains the maximal value inside the region.

So for maxima  or minima $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}=0$ and $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}=0$

[Using Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=d%2Fdx+%28x%5E15%281-x%29y%5E15%281-y%29%2F%281-xy%29%5E15%29)
$$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}=-\frac{x^{14}(y-1)y^{15}(x^2y-16x+15)}{(1-xy)^{16}}=0$$ Which gives $$x^2y-16x+15=0\tag{1}$$ Similarly $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}=0$ gives $$y^2x-16y+15=0\tag{2}$$ Subtracting
$(1)$ and $(2)$, we obtain
$$ x^2y-y^2x+16y-16x=0 $$
So we get $$(xy-16)(x-y)=0 $$ which gives $x=y$ or $xy=16$. Since $0<x,y<1$, so $xy=16$ is not possible. So we have for maxima or minima $$x=y\tag{3}$$
So we are down to function of single variable $$ F(x)=\frac{x^{30}(1-x)^2}{(1-x^2)^{15}}$$ where $0<x<1$.
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: solution to $(1)$ is $1; 3.405 ; -4.405$. and $(1)$ is necessary for maximum (i think)

Comment: @MahammadYusifov But note that $1$ is not in the domain.

Comment: There is a maximum as $x,y\to 1$ in the domain. There is also a finite maximum apparently at [this point](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=local+maxima+%28x%5E%2815%29%281-x%29y%5E%2815%29%281-y%29%29%2F%28%281-xy%29%5E%2815%29%29%2C0%3Cx%3C1%2C0%3Cy%3C1)

Comment: @ТymaGaidash Thanks a lot. So what is the maximum value? I mean the approx maximum value? The link you gave is showing $0$. Also the answer is telling that there is no maximum.

Comment: @ТymaGaidash It would be really helpful if you would write as an answer. I will with utmost respect accept it.

Comment: I meant that eq $(1)$ implies answer is $x = 1$ which is forbidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the limit of $f(x,y)$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $(1,1)$ along the path $x=y$. Then
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)}f(x,y)=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^{30}(1-x)^2}{(1-x^2)^{15}}=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^{30}}{(1-x)^{13}(1+x)^{15}}=\infty.$$
This shows that $f(x,y)$ does not have a global maximum in the given domain.

At any local extremum you have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$. You have already shown that this implies $x=y$. Then also $\frac{d}{dx}f(x,x)=0$ where
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x,x)=\frac{x^{29}(1-x)^2(x^2+x-15)}{(1-x^2)^{16}},$$
but the numerator is easily verified to be nonzero for $0<x<1$. So $f(x,y)$ does not even have any local extremum in the given domain.